# Postgres Data Type Declarations and Typing, What's the Difference Between Double Colon and Not

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting

### Main Question

I was wondering what the difference between declaring a type using double semicolon `::` is, vs *not* using `::` in Postgres.

### Example

```sql
INTERVAL '1 day'
-- vs
'1 day'::INTERVAL
```

### So Many More Questions...

- Is `::` type casting? Like casting a string to an `INTERVAL`.
- What would you call the first example *without* using `::`, or is that how you define that data type without casting?
- Are there any benefits to use one over the other?
- Was one introduced before the other?
- Are there speed benefits?
- Is one method standardized and prefered over the other within the community?
- Is there a community style guidelines document?
- Is this unique to Postgres, or applicable to SQL as well?

Sorry for all the questions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might refer to `INTERVAL '1 day'` as an interval *literal*.  This means, as written and without any casting, it states a literal Postgres `INTERVAL` value.  On the other hand, `'1 day'::INTERVAL` is actually a *cast* of the text `1 day` to make it an `INTERVAL` value.

The `::` casting syntax is not part of the ANSI standard, and is specific to Postgres.  Note that `CAST('1 day' AS INTERVAL)` is more or less identical to using the double colon `'1 day'::INTERVAL` syntax.

If you were concerned about having to one day possibly port your Postgres SQL code to another database, then you might stick with using `CAST()` over `::`, the former which is supported on most other databases.

In terms of performance, `INTERVAL '1 day'` does not require Postgres to do any explicit casting operation, while `CAST` or `::` do require an explicit cast.  There could be some small performance differences there.

Comment: I feel silly seeing `literal` now. That's the word I couldn't come to find at the tip of my mind: `type literal` ‍♂️. Thanks for answering the additional questions and going into the *why* for them.

Comment: Note that `interval '1 day'` is a Postgres specific variant of the standard ANSI SQL `interval '1' day`